# Find without L'Hopital : $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}xe^{x^2} \left(∫_0^xe^{-t^2}dt-∫_0^∞e^{-t^2 } dt\right) = \ ?$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}xe^{x^2} \left(∫_0^xe^{-t^2}dt-∫_0^∞e^{-t^2 } dt\right) = \ ?$$
I found this limit using L'Hopital's rule and error function. That is relatively easy I am wondering if there is any suggestion to find it without using L'Hopital's rule.

The final answer is $-\frac{1}{2}$.  Another version:$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}x2^{x^2} \left(∫_0^x2^{-t^2}dt-∫_0^∞2^{-t^2 } dt\right) = \ ?$$Suggested by Jalil Hajimir

Comment: For the first problem, at least, there are very accurate upper and lower bounds for the Gaussian integral which can be used to get the limit.

Comment: And, I think the way we derive the estimates for Gaussian integral (via a change of variable $t\mapsto t+x/t$, a similar argument should give bounds for the second integral as well, which will hopefully be close enough to give a precise limit when $x$ goes to infinity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you seem to be familiar with the error function, you face
$$y=xe^{x^2} \left(∫_0^xe^{-t^2}dt-∫_0^∞e^{-t^2 } dt\right)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}x e^{x^2} \left( \text{erf}(x)-1\right)=-\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}x e^{x^2}\text{erfc}(x)$$

Now, using the asymptotic series (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Asymptotic_expansion))
$$\text{erfc}(x)\sim\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{(2n - 1)!!}{(2x^2)^n}$$ makes
$$y= -\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4 x^2}-\frac{3}{8x^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^6}\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

It also gives a good approximation value of $y$

Comment: The _asymptotic_ series you gave can not be called "Taylor series". Your answer is of course right but I suggest changing the equal sign to $\sim$.

Comment: @KemonoChen. You are totally right. Edited. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 2):

Using integration by parts,

$$ \int_x^\infty e^{-t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t = \int_x^\infty \frac{2te^{-t^2}}{2t} \,\mathrm{d}t = \frac{e^{-x^2}}{2x} - \int_x^\infty \frac{e^{-t^2}}{2t^2} \,\mathrm{d}t  ,$$ and

$$ \int_x^\infty \frac{e^{-t^2}}{2t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t =  \frac{e^{-x^2}}{4x^3} - \int_x^\infty \frac{3e^{-t^2}}{4t^4}\,\mathrm{d}t. $$

Since the integrands are always non-negative, this gives $$\frac{e^{-x^2}}{2x} - \frac{e^{-x^2}}{4x^3}   \le \int_x^\infty e^{-t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t \le \frac{e^{-x^2}}{2x}.$$

Thus, $$ xe^{x^2}\left( \int_0^x e^{-t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t - \int_0^\infty e^{-t^2} \,\mathrm{d}t \right) = - xe^{x^2} \int_x^\infty e^{-t^2} \,\mathrm{d}t = -\frac12 + O(x^{-2}),$$ and the limit is $-1/2$.

It is straightforward to replace the $e$s in the above by any constant $a > 1$, since $a^{x^2} = e^{ (\sqrt{\ln(a)} x)^2}$, at which point you can rescale $y = \sqrt{\ln(a)} x$ and proceed as above.

Comment: Surely, you need some condition on $a$, else $\ln(a) < 0$ for certain in which case $\sqrt{\ln (a)}$ does not have a clear meaning.

Comment: You're quite right, it should be $a > 1$ - for $0<a<1,$ the whole thing would diverge since  $a^{x^2 - t^2}  \ge 1$ for $t > x$. Corrected.

Comment: +1.....This is approx to what I was typing when your A appeared but yours is better than mine would have been... To the proposer: The idea is that with $f(t)=e^{-t^2},$ for $t>0$ we have $\int f(t)dt=\int (-f'(t)/2t))dt=\int (-1/2t)df(t).$

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning that  both $1/t^4$ and $e^{-t^2}$ are positive & decreasing for $t>1,$ so for $x>1$ we have $0<\int_x^{\infty}(3e^{-t^2}/4t^4)dt<$ $e^{-x^2}\int_x^{\infty}(3/4t^4)dt=$ $e^{-x^2}/4x^3.$